# Is "Sripada Srivallabha Charitamrutam" accepted within the Orthodox Hindu community?

Tags: dattatreya

The origins of the book "Sripada Srivallabha Charitamrutam" does not appear to be supported by solid public evidence. While my research has not provided concrete details about its authorship, it seems to be associated with the "World Teacher Trust" organization, suggesting a role in its preservation and dissemination. Is this organization widely recognized and respected in India? What motivated them to publish the book, and do they hold the copyrights, why and how?

Claims suggest that the book was authored approximately 700 years ago but remained undisclosed until recent times. Validating such an assertion poses a challenge, and it is reasonable to approach such claims with discernment. Seeking credible historical evidence or scholarly assessments may provide a more comprehensive understanding of the book's authenticity.

I am keen to grasp the viewpoint of orthodox Hindus concerning "Sripada Srivallabha Charitamrutam." Is this book regarded as an authoritative religious text within orthodox Hinduism? Or, is the entire narrative surrounding this book a product of inspiration from a group of devotees in our current times? How can we be certain that this book is genuinely ancient? Who concealed it for such an extended period? Is there any evidence regarding the existence of the original manuscripts? Have these manuscripts undergone carbon testing for verification?

It's surprising that there's no publicly available information about it.

The book makes bold claims, suggesting extraordinary revelations, like the advaitic fusion of Dattatreya's soul with Lord Hanumanth's in the Himalayas and his subsequent reincarnation as "Sai Nath" in this era.

It appears that the book somehow advocates for Shirdi Sai Baba, or at the very least, Shirdi Sai Baba devotees seem to derive benefits from the prophecies associated with him.

I apologize if my inquiries sound disrespectful. My sole intention is to shed light on this topic and address these fundamental doubts for better clarity.

Thanks.